# Set the PDF file name in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am generating a PDF file with C#. The title of the file is assigned automatic. I want to set the file name when I open the folderbrowserdialog . How can i do that?

```
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
     string caminho = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
     var pasta2 = caminho.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
     Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 42, 35);

     PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pasta2 + "\\Relatorio.pdf", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
```

Comment: `FolderBrowserDialog` is for selecting directories, not saving files. Do you mean `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: how can i transform this PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pasta2 + "\\Relatorio.pdf", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)); in savefile dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something Like, You have to use `SaveFileDialog` , For more information visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

```
SaveFileDialog dialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog1.Title = "Save file as...";
dialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (dialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dialog1.FileName);
}
```

you use `dialog1.FileName` when creating your `FileStream`:

```
PdfWriter writertest = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(dialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create));
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: It appears like an error , i want to set the name directly in the folderbrowserdialog

Comment: You can't set the Filename in folderBrowseDialog use SaveFileDialog

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the Filename in **FolderBrowserDialog**, you need to use **SaveFileDialog**. Try this sample code

```
  saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Akshay.pdf";

       saveFileDialog1.FileOk +=new CancelEventHandler(saveFileDialog1_FileOk);
     saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();


private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Done");
           // do the PDF Method here 
        }
```

Comment: how can i transform this PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pasta2 + "\\Relatorio.pdf", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)); in savefile dialog?

Comment: I have Updated Answer, Write the PDF methods in Event Method